# How to use ViewBinding in a RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Can I use ViewBindings to replace `findViewById` in this typical `RecyclerView.Adapter` initialization code? I can't set a `binding` val in the object as the ViewHolders are different per cell.

```
class CardListAdapter(private val cards: LiveData<List<Card>>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CardListAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {

    class CardViewHolder(val cardView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(cardView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
        val binding = CardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return CardViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val title = holder.cardView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
        val description = holder.cardView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.description)
        val value = holder.cardView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.value)
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: "the ViewHolders are different per cell" -- so have each `ViewHolder` do its own binding by means of its dedicated binding object. Pass the `CardBinding` to the `CardViewHolder` constructor so it has that binding object. IOW, this is no different than using data binding with `RecyclerView`, and that combination has been used for a few years.

Comment: I found you can also use `CardBinding.bind(holder.cardView)`. I wonder whether the `bind` method has worse performance?

Comment: Checkout my blog on viewbinding I explained anti-pattern and patterns regarding binding in adapter fragment and activity, it's in depth with internals as well  [Androidbites|Viewbinding](https://chetangupta.net/viewbinding/)

Comment: yes you can use see my answer

Answer (score 247, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the generated binding class object to the holder class constructor. In below example, I have `row_payment` XML file for `RecyclerView` item and the generated class is `RowPaymentBinding` so  like this

```kotlin
class PaymentAdapter(private val paymentList: List<PaymentBean>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PaymentAdapter.PaymentHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PaymentHolder {
        val itemBinding = RowPaymentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return PaymentHolder(itemBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PaymentHolder, position: Int) {
        val paymentBean: PaymentBean = paymentList[position]
        holder.bind(paymentBean)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = paymentList.size

    class PaymentHolder(private val itemBinding: RowPaymentBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
        fun bind(paymentBean: PaymentBean) {
            itemBinding.tvPaymentInvoiceNumber.text = paymentBean.invoiceNumber
            itemBinding.tvPaymentAmount.text = paymentBean.totalAmount
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you pass the root view to the parent class of Viewholder like this `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root)` by accessing the passed binding class object.

Comment: Very clean. Thank you. An improvement to the bind function would be:
`fun bind(paymentBean: PaymentBean) = with(itemBinding) {

    tvPaymentInvoiceNumber.text = paymentBean.invoiceNumber

    tvPaymentAmount.text = paymentBean.totalAmount

}`

...to avoid repeatedly writing of `itemBinding`.

Comment: Or alternatively to avoid repeating 'itemBinding' you could use 'itemBinding.apply { ... }'

Comment: @robsn yeah, we can do that.. but that wasn't the intention of this answer and I wanted to make it easy for the beginners that's why I didn't use scope function.

Comment: If you are using databinding, what's the purpose of doing `itemBinding.tvPaymentInvoiceNumber.text = paymentBean.invoiceNumber` and so forth? You can just do `binding.executePendingBindings()`

Comment: @Chisko I am not using DataBinding in this example and tbh I am not a fan of data-binding.

Comment: Why can't you leave the names as default when you install Recyclerview instead of paymentHolder paymentWhatever

Comment: @EduardUnruh What should be used here instead of PaymentWhatever?

Comment: what if I used databinding utils isn't better?

Comment: @Somesh Kumar I have a similar (android) issue with an ItemTouchHelper here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903704/android-how-to-use-viewbinding-in-itemtouchhelper-swipe  I would appreciate any insights or ideas on how to fix.

Answer (score 38):

Attach the `binding` to the ViewHolder instead of the View

```
class CardViewHolder(val binding: CardBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

You pass the binding, the binding passes `binding.root` to `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
    val binding = CardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return CardViewHolder(binding)
}
```

Then access anywhere with:

```
holder.binding.title
```

Comment: you should create the binding in `onCreateViewHolder` instead of `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: (because this answer currently works-around the idea of the `ViewHolder` only looking up references in `onCreateViewHolder` -> `ViewHolder` constructor, and instead runs `findViewById` for each `onBindViewHolder` call, eliminating the ViewHolder's ability to actually "hold views" - the other answer is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427658/2413303)

Comment: You are entirely correct. That's what my second option is. The first one shouldn't be used as per your reasoning. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to edit the answer itself to reflect that.

Comment: @A1m I have a similar (android) issue with an ItemTouchHelper here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903704/android-how-to-use-viewbinding-in-itemtouchhelper-swipe I would appreciate any insights or ideas on how to fix.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a simple and reusable one:

```kotlin
class ViewBindingVH constructor(val binding: ViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    
    companion object {
        inline fun create(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            crossinline block: (inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, attach: Boolean) -> ViewBinding
        ) = ViewBindingVH(block(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }
}


class CardAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewBindingVH>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewBindingVH {
        return ViewBindingVH.create(parent, CardBinding::inflate)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewBindingVH, position: Int) {
        (holder.binding as CardBinding).apply {
            //bind model to view
            title.text = "some text"
            descripiton.text = "some text"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: will this cause the inflater to be done once?

Comment: @Moustafa EL-Saghier  No, It's just a little decoration of ViewHolder.

Comment: Do you know any way the inflater works once for multiple views types of same view holder

Comment: @Moustafa EL-Saghier  I haven't understood what you mean, a view holder should coresspond just one view type.

Comment: I've different view types with different view holders in same recycler but there's a view type repeating multiple, so I ask any way 6to make the views holder inflated once if the view type repeated?

Comment: If I haven't misunderstood you, what you want is that viewholder of repeated view type should create just once. Actually，it depends configuraiton of recyclerview.Each view type has one cached viewholder defaultly, when a item of this type is out of recyclerview, it's viewholder will recycled and reused to binding new data.

Comment: yes i know that but, my issue is there's a section called Products and it's shown many in home recycler view so was woundering if i can make the onCreateViewHolder being called once for the multiple view type or not

Comment: If what you mean is The products scetion has different view types, no. Recycerview will check if there is a viewholder for each view type in cache pool.If not, onCreateViewHolder will invoked.

Comment: @Alan W.  I have a similar (android) issue with an ItemTouchHelper here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903704/android-how-to-use-viewbinding-in-itemtouchhelper-swipe I would appreciate any insights or ideas on how to fix.

Answer (score 6):

You may use view-binding like this  :

```
package com.example.kotlinprogramming.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.kotlinprogramming.data.HobbiesData
import com.example.kotlinprogramming.databinding.ItemHobbieBinding

class HobbiesAdapter(var context: Context, var hobbiesList: List<HobbiesData>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<HobbiesAdapter.HobbiesViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HobbiesViewHolder {
    val view = ItemHobbieBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context) , parent,false)
    return HobbiesViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HobbiesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val hobbie = hobbiesList.get(position)
    holder.viewBinding.tvHobbie.text = hobbie.title
}

inner class HobbiesViewHolder(var viewBinding: ItemHobbieBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewBinding.root) {
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return hobbiesList.size
}

}
```

Here is item_hobbies.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="12dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHobbie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:text="Hobbie1"
    />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're ok with reflection, I have a much easier way to do this.
Just call ViewGroup.toBinding() then you can get the binding object you want.
But since we're talk about reflection, remember you have to modify your proguard-rule to make it work even for proguard.

```kotlin
// inside adapter
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return MainViewHolder(parent.toBinding())
}

// ViewHolder
class MainViewHolder(private val binding: AdapterMainBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(data: String) {
        binding.name.text = data
    }
}

// The magic reflection can reused everywhere.
inline fun <reified V : ViewBinding> ViewGroup.toBinding(): V {
    return V::class.java.getMethod(
        "inflate",
        LayoutInflater::class.java,
        ViewGroup::class.java,
        Boolean::class.java
    ).invoke(null, LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false) as V
}
```

I put all this into an open source project you can take a look as well.
Not only for Adapter usage but also include Activity and Fragment. And do let me know if you have any comment. Thanks.

https://github.com/Jintin/BindingExtension

Comment: clean and simple, is it possible to use it with adapter with CompositeItem for section sorting ?

Comment: Do you mean ConcatAdapter or SortedList? Both should work but I'm not sure if it what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm curios, is this okay to use reflection in that case? Think it's not

Comment: this reflection function will be broken on obfuscated cmiiw

Comment: @AdeDyas yes, so in the README page there's how to avoid obfuscated  broken guide - https://github.com/Jintin/BindingExtension#usage

Comment: niiiceee @Jintin

Answer (score 0):

just pass your model calss into xml and set these data into xml  this code look fine and add a method where you add these data into binding like you don,t need to fine the id for this

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.setData(listData[position])

}


fun setData(model: ListData) {
        with(binding) {
            data = model
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use data binding like this.

```
class CardListAdapter(
        private val mActivity: FragmentActivity?
    ) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
         private var mCustomLayoutBinding: CustomLayoutBinding? = null

          inner class MyViewHolder(val mBinding: CustomLayoutBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mBinding.getRoot())
     override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            if (layoutInflater == null)
                layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

            var viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder? = null
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

       viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater)
                 return viewHolder!!
            }
            private fun getViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            inflater: LayoutInflater
        ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            mCustomLayoutBinding =
                DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(this!!.mAssistanceLogCustomLayoutBinding!!)
        }
          override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val taskModal = mArrayList.get(position)
             holder.mBinding.txtTitle.setText(taskModal.title)
              }
              override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return assistanceArrayList.size
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            return position
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took what [Alan W. did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62058833) and added Generics to it.

```
class ViewBindingVH <VB: ViewBinding> constructor(val binding: VB) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

companion object {
    inline fun <VB: ViewBinding> create(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        crossinline block: (inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, attach: Boolean) -> VB
    ) = ViewBindingVH<VB>(block(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}}
```

The implementation is very easy and you avoid the casting on the adapter class:

```
class PlayerViewHolder : ListAdapter<Rate, ViewBindingVH<ChartItemBinding>>(RateDiff) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewBindingVH<ChartItemBinding> =
    ViewBindingVH.create(parent, ChartItemBinding::inflate)


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewBindingVH<ChartItemBinding>, position: Int) {
    val item = currentList[position]
    holder.binding.apply {
        
    }
}}

object RateDiff: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Rate>(){
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Rate, newItem: Rate): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
}
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Rate, newItem: Rate): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
}}
```

Comment: I considered using generics, but I gave up it because of mulit view types. generics limits your adapter to just one view type.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<T : Any, VB : ViewBinding>(
     private var dataList: ArrayList<T>) 
: RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewViewHolder<VB>>() 
{   
      protected var bindingInterface: GenericSimpleRecyclerBindingInterface<T, VB>? = null

   class MyViewViewHolder<VB : ViewBinding>(val viewBinding: VB) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewBinding.root) {
        fun <T : Any> bind(
            item: T,
            position: Int,
            bindingInterface: GenericSimpleRecyclerBindingInterface<T, VB>
            ) = bindingInterface.bindData(item, position, viewBinding)
        }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun updateList(list: ArrayList<T>) {
       dataList.clear()
       dataList.addAll(list)
       notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):MyViewViewHolder<VB> {
       val view = inflateView(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
       return MyViewViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewViewHolder<VB>, position: Int) {
       val item = dataList[position]
       holder.bind(item, position, bindingInterface!!)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size

    abstract fun inflateView(inflater: LayoutInflater): VB
}

interface GenericSimpleRecyclerBindingInterface<T : Any, VB : ViewBinding> {
     fun bindData(item: T, position: Int, viewBinding: VB)
}
```