# Move to View Biding for Adapter: Can't get it working

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make the move to View Binding in order the migrate to the 1.8.0 of the Gradle Plugin. I found a lot of posts but somehow I can't get it working for my Adapter:

```
class JustPlayedAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<JustPlayedViewHolder>() {

    private var context: Context? = null

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return lastPlayed.count()

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): JustPlayedViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.just_played_row, parent, false)

        context = parent.context

        return JustPlayedViewHolder(cellForRow)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JustPlayedViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.tijd.text = lastPlayed[position][0]
        holder.itemView.artiest.text = lastPlayed[position][1]
        holder.itemView.titel.text = lastPlayed[position][2]

        holder.itemView.tijd.contentDescription = lastPlayed[position][0]
        holder.itemView.artiest.contentDescription = lastPlayed[position][1]
        holder.itemView.titel.contentDescription = lastPlayed[position][2]

        holder.itemView.albumart.setImageBitmap(lastPlayedAlbumart[position])

        if (lastPlayed[position][3] != "") {

            //Apple music link beschikbaar

            holder.itemView.isClickable = true
            holder.itemView.appleMusicIcon.isVisible = true

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

                println("stationAPP: appleMusicURL = " + lastPlayed[position][3])

                //open Apple Music
                val appleMusicURL = lastPlayed[position][3]

                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(appleMusicURL))
                context!!.startActivity(intent)

            }

        } else {

            //Apple music link NIET beschikbaar

            holder.itemView.isClickable = false
            holder.itemView.appleMusicIcon.isVisible = false

        }

    }

}

class JustPlayedViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

I manage to get it working for my Activities, but not for my 2 adapters.

I used the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427658/833647 but that didn’t work for me. Who can help me out here?

See the answer which is different than the answers in that post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427658/833647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out. I had to add the JustPlayedViewHolder class within the JustPlayedAdapter class:

```
class JustPlayedAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<JustPlayedAdapter.JustPlayedViewHolder>() {
    class JustPlayedViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val binding = JustPlayedRowBinding.bind(view)

    }

...

}
```